VBA Error 1004 occurs when manipulating a table
VBA returns an error in certain occasions where I work with a table.
I have en excel worksheet, let's call it Target, that is used by some colleagues. I manipulated this Target file a VBA macro and I create a table in one of the worksheets. Notice that I also apply some filter on the table and I manipulate the filtered rows (with an On Error statement in case there are no rows provided). If somebody deletes some rows from one of the tables in the Target file before the Macro is run, the VBA macro stops the execution of the code.
I have tried to break down the method in two different methods and VBA returns me the error 1004: The worksheet data for a table needs to be on the same sheet as the table.
I am a bit puzzle because the error only occurs when some rows are deleted (CTRL + -). If on the other hand, the rows are erased (theie content is cleared), this error does not occur.
I can imagine that finding a solution for this problem is not posssible with the few information I provided. I know that this is not much to work on but maybe you can give me a hint on where to start to look for the problem. That would already help me a lot.

Can you post the code?  I'd say you're correct - finding a solution to this problem is not possible with the little information provided.

@DarrenBartrup-Cook The whole code is quite long and extensive (pages of code).
But I can provide the code where the macro stops executing:
lastRow1 = Sheets("OPEN").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Then it does not execute:
Sheets("OPEN").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:CP" & lastRow1), , xlYes).Name = "openOrders" 

@DarrenBartrup-Cook the aim for now would be to understand what would be the name of this problem/error. I would do some research on my own after that and try to find a solution to it. I will also make sure to post the answer afterwards

This is more based on a hint as I was trying to find a solution to another problem.
I think that the problem occurs when someone is trying to make changes manually to the table deleting some of its rows with CRTL + -. Since the table is created in VBA with the code ListObject any changes made to the table manually lead to some problem. After creating the table in VBA, it should be Unlisted with the code below to make sure any manual changes do not lead to error.
Sheets("SHEET NAME").ListObject("TABLE NAME").Unlist


The error message indicates you issue the command when another worksheet is active (other than "OPEN"). Use this concept:
set shOpen = Sheets("OPEN")
lastRow1 = shOpen.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
set loOpen = shOpen.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, shOpen.Range("A1:CP" & lastRow1), , xlYes)
loOpen.Name = "openOrders" 


No. Unfortunately, this does not seem to solve the problem. Notice that I even tried to save with the SaveAs command and close with the Close command the Target worksheet and then reopen it. This did not solve the problem. Any other hint? Thanks @AcsErno for helping out
